# Set hostname on first boot before network.service

Tags: debian, systemd, dhcp, hostname

I have a firstboot.service that, from a stock OS image creates a unique hostname based on the MAC of the primary ethernet adapter.  It runs as expected during boot but the hostname that gets registered with DHCP is still the default hostname as set from the kernel.  So after the device boots, I can ping it at `defaultname.mynet.lan` but when I login and call `hostname` it displays `foo-XXXX` as expected.

As you can see below, the service is registered to run before `network.target`.  As you may guess I'm using `systemd-networkd` and `systemd-resolved` for  networking.

- Do I have to do something else to propagate the hostname to running processes?
- Can I set the hostname earlier in the boot process, if so what target should I use?

**firstboot.service**

```
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/hostname
Before=network.target
After=local-fs.target
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/local/sbin/firstboot.sh"
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

**firstboot.sh**

```
HOST_PREFIX=${HOST_PREFIX:-"foo"}
NET_DEVICE=${NET_DEVICE:="eth0"}
LAST_MAC4=$(sed -rn "s/^.*([0-9A-F:]{5})$/\1/gi;s/://p" /sys/class/net/${NET_DEVICE}/address)
NEW_HOSTNAME=${HOST_PREFIX}-${LAST_MAC4:-0000}

echo $NEW_HOSTNAME > /etc/hostname
/bin/hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

Comment: If you are trying to change the hostname from the default hostname you can do that in systemd by checking with `ConditionHost=ubuntu*`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing ensures that your `firstboot.service` runs before `systemd-networkd` is started. You have to use

```
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target
```

instead of `Before=network.target` to achieve that.  As `man systemd.special` explains:

> **network-pre.target:**
>   This passive target unit may be pulled in by services that want
>   to run before any network
>   is set up, for example for the purpose of setting up a firewall.
>   All network management
>   software orders itself after this target, but does not pull it in.

You'll also need `DefaultDependencies=false` to avoid the implicit dependency on `basic.target` (see `man systemd.service`).

Comment: Why do we need `wants` here? Isn't `before` enough for the requirement?

Comment: The `Wants` directive "pulls in" the `network-pre.target`. Otherwise it may not be present at all, making the ordering ineffective.